# Sectional curvature of the manifold and submanifold

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry, curvature, submanifold

I have a complete and homogeneously regular Riemannian manifold $M$, embedded isometrically in a Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$. And $N \subset M$ is a closed and embedded submanifold, not necessarily connected.

I know that the second fundamental form of $M$ and $N$ are bounded, with norm less than or equal to $1/16$. I know that the sectional curvature of $M$ is at most $1/64$.

Is there a way (with this information) to calculate the sectional curvature of $N$? Or will they both have the same curvature?

I scaled the metric, where the sectional curvature is multiplied by a constant $\lambda^{-1}$.

Comment: Do you know Gauss' equation?

Comment: @Didier Yes, but using it I don't come up with a good estimate. I don't know how to use the fact of having the scaled metric.

Comment: Actually I have no idea of what you mean by "I have scaled the metric" and "how to use the fact": what is the precise statement, and then, what have you done? It is hard to tell if the original question has something like $\lambda^2$ in the different constant you stated, *etc.*